# RegExp for kubernetes pod name

Tags: regex, logging, kubernetes, fluentd

I'm using Fluentd as my log shipper in kubernetes, with a [plugin extracting metadata using a RegExp](https://github.com/fabric8io/fluent-plugin-kubernetes_metadata_filter/blob/master/lib/fluent/plugin/filter_kubernetes_metadata.rb#L49).
The plugin currently uses the following regexp -
`'var\.log\.containers\.(?<pod_name>[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*)_(?<namespace>[^_]+)_(?<container_name>.+)-(?<docker_id>[a-z0-9]{64})\.log$'`
For parsing records structured like so -
`kubernetes.soluto.var.log.containers.my-nice-api-67459fc4f6-g9vk7_namespace-name_container-name-1e1eeab6b6ce257cf6a7a03057159f3b0873dcd5c0cc713cd8c43ed66c5b6b03.log`

I'm trying to alter the regexp so it will separate the `pod_name` value into 2 parts -

1. the pod name derived from the deployment name/explicitly given by the .yaml configuration
2. The hash appended to the pod_name (separated from the pod_name by 2 hyphens)

I could've used the hyphen character as a delimiter and be done with it easily, but since the `pod_name` itself may contain hyphens this is impossible.

I therefore have to find a pattern that will capture a group that will contain the pattern without the last two hyphen delimited parts.

I've constructed [this regexp](https://regex101.com/r/b3JHIM/1) and played around with it, but it does not behave as expected. Would love any help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the group named "pod_name" should just contain the pod name derived from the deployment name, try this:

```
kubernetes\.var\.log\.containers\.(?:(?<pod_name>[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*))-(?<=-)[a-z0-9]+-(?:(?<=-)[a-z0-9]+(?=_))_(?<namespace>[^_]+)_(?<container_name>.+)-(?<docker_id>[a-z0-9]{64})\.log
```

if the group named "pod_name" should contain both parts, i.e. the pod name derived from the deployment name and the hash appended to it, try this:

```
kubernetes\.var\.log\.containers\.(?:(?<pod_name>[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*-(?<=-)[a-z0-9]+-(?:(?<=-)[a-z0-9]+(?=_))))_(?<namespace>[^_]+)_(?<container_name>.+)-(?<docker_id>[a-z0-9]{64})\.log
```

Comment: Thanks, it totally did the trick! I really should brush up on my RegExp skills.